# How to add filter on node list in a custom module?

Tags: 6, views

I am developing a module. In that module I have a page to list all the nodes of a specific type to user.

I need to:

1- show the nodes each on a row with ' Edit | Delete ' link in each row.

2- I also need to show a dropdown to give the user ability to filter the nodes by one of the node field.

I've created the first one but I don't know how to add a custom filter to the output.

Would you help me ?

I am working on Drupal 6.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Views 3 and within CCK you have listed allowed values for the field in question, you can set it up like this.

1. Select the field in question with the allowed values option, eg, in Filters, select `'Content: Field Name (field_name) - ALLOWED VALUES'`
2. Click on EXPOSE.
3. Click in the values and select them all.
4. Click `Limit list to selected items`.
5. Save it.

You should now have an exposed filter with a drop down that limits the view to that field.

Answer (score -1):

You can use views for listing nodes of specific types.
Also, in views, you can use Contextual filters for other options.
Please explore more options of views and you will find every option there.
Thanks.

Comment: Answers should go into much more detail. I do not believe that a drop down list on an exposed filter can be easily populated using a field from the nodes. Please expand to let the OP know how to accomplish what he is trying to do.

Comment: But if I build a page display view I guess setting permission is a little difficult, because I have some other views and give unregistered user view permission but for the issue I asked in question I want just authenticated ones see the view. As I remember I can't set permission for views separately.

Comment: @hd. That's where you remember wrong. Different views have different permissions, for sure.